# Syntax to include one of two possible keys

Tags: typescript

If someone has a type or interface similar to this:

```
interface Props {
value: string
somethingElse?: boolean
}
```

and they want to accomplish:

```
interface PropsOne {
value: string
somethingElse?: boolean
onChange: (s: string) => void
}

interface PropsTwo {
value: string
somethingElse?: boolean
onAccept: (s: string) => void
}

type Props = PropsOne | PropsTwo
```

what syntax can be used to accomplish this without re-writing the entire interface or type multiple times? I'm positive I've seen a syntax similar to the one below, but I can't make my LSP happy.

```
type Props = {
value: string
somethingElse?: boolean
} & ({
onAccept: (s: string) => void
} | {
onChange: (s: string) => void
})
```

Currently, this accepts the `onAccept` method, or whichever comes first in that attempted ternary-ish thing, but the following property isn't included in the props object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the unique props of Props 1 & Props 2 to be exclusive of one another you can write it like this.

```
type Props = {
value: string
somethingElse?: boolean
} & ({
onAccept: (s: string) => void
onChange?:never;
} | {
onChange: (s: string) => void
onAccept?:never
})
```

In this example if you pass a value for `onAccept` ts will throw an error if you also pass a value for `onChange`, and the same will be true visa-versa. This is a discriminated union.

Comment: Thanks! One thing I want to point out for anyone coming across this later, make sure to make the never types optional. That's where I was getting hung up before.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do something like this.

```js
// Define the base interface with common properties:
interface BaseProps {
  value: string;
  somethingElse?: boolean;
}

// Extend the base interface to create PropsOne:
interface PropsOne extends BaseProps {
  onChange: (s: string) => void;
}

// Extend the base interface to create PropsTwo:
interface PropsTwo extends BaseProps {
  onAccept: (s: string) => void;
}

// Create a union type for Props combining PropsOne and PropsTwo:
type Props = PropsOne | PropsTwo;
```